# i have implemented a method for on click popup menu but my app is crashing on run time

Tags: android

i have implemented popup menu method(openDialogManger) in my activity . Basically i want a popmenu when i click an item in my list view. I have implemented the method but my app is crashing when i click first item in my listview .

This is my Activity where i have implemented this method

```
package com.example.shivnandan.fit;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity1 extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener

{
    ListView list;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");


        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
     //   registerForContextMenu(list);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);
        list.setAdapter(new shivvAdapter(this));


        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()


        {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                if (position == 0)

                {
                   openDialogManager();

                }


                if (position == 1)

                {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Age Selected ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

                if (position == 2)

                {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Height Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

                if (position == 3)

                {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Weight Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
                if (position == 4)

                {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Reset Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

            }
        });
    }
    public void openDialogManager()
    {

        final CharSequence[] items = {"Male", "Female"};

        new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .setTitle("Gender")
                .setSingleChoiceItems(items, 0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        switch (which)
                        {

                            case 0:
                                Toast.makeText( MainActivity1.this, "male ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                dialog.dismiss();
                                break;

                            case 1:
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity1.this, "female ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                dialog.dismiss();
                                break;
                        }
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                    {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                })
        .show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
    {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START))
        {

            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
        else
        {

            super.onBackPressed();
        }



    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Setting ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }

        if(id==R.id.Change_photo)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Change Your Photo",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera)
        {

        }
        else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery)
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);

            startActivity(i);
        }
        else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow)
        {


        }
    else if (id == R.id.nav_manage)
     {

       }


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

}
class SingleRow2
{
    String title;
    //String description;
    int  image;
    SingleRow2(String title )
    {

        this.title =title;
        // this.description = description;
        //this.image = image;
    }

}
class shivvAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    ArrayList<SingleRow> list;
    Context context;
    shivvAdapter(Context c)
    {
        context = c;
        list=new ArrayList<SingleRow>();
        Resources res = c.getResources();
        String[] titles=res.getStringArray(R.array.profiletitle);
        // String[] descriptions=res.getStringArray(R.array.description);
        int[] images = {R.drawable.one,R.drawable.two,R.drawable.three,R.drawable.two,R.drawable.two,R.drawable.two};
        for (int i =0 ; i<5 ; i++)
        {


            list.add(new SingleRow(titles[i],images[i]));
        }



    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return list.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup)
    {

        LayoutInflater inflater =(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View  row =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row2,viewGroup,false);
        TextView title= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        //  TextView description= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        //ImageView image= (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        SingleRow temp = list.get(i);
        title.setText(temp.title);
        //description.setText(temp.description);
        //image.setImageResource(temp.image);
        return row;
    }

}
```

And this my log error exception

```
04-19 20:32:59.892 7483-7483/com.example.shivnandan.fit E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: com.example.shivnandan.fit, PID: 7483
                                                                          android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:562)
                                                                              at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:272)
                                                                              at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
                                                                              at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:298)
                                                                              at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:987)
                                                                              at com.example.shivnandan.fit.MainActivity1.openDialogManager(MainActivity1.java:157)
                                                                              at com.example.shivnandan.fit.MainActivity1$2.onItemClick(MainActivity1.java:83)
                                                                              at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:300)
                                                                              at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1143)
                                                                              at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3044)
                                                                              at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3860)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5253)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

And this is Method that i have implemented

```
public void openDialogManager()
    {

        final CharSequence[] items = {"Male", "Female"};

        new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .setTitle("Gender")
                .setSingleChoiceItems(items, 0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        switch (which)
                        {

                            case 0:
                                Toast.makeText( MainActivity1.this, "male ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                dialog.dismiss();
                                break;

                            case 1:
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity1.this, "female ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                dialog.dismiss();
                                break;
                        }
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                    {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                })
        .show();
```

Comment: It seems like you activity is dead at the time you call openDialogManager(), try with passing activity context instead of using getApplicationContext()

Comment: can you please elaborate your answer please .

Comment: thank you it worked JNI_OnLoad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mean that, why don't you try like this,

```
  listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long rowId) {


        AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                MainActivity.this);
                adb.setTitle("ABC");
                adb.setMessage(" selected Item is="
                +parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
                adb.setPositiveButton("Ok", null);
                adb.show();    

    }
});
```

Instead of using this getApplicationContext(), use the Activity context , I strongly think that this is what you error is about as it is saying `BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?`
Let me know if it does not solve the issue